# Why does it cost more gas to transfer on contract one with less decimals than one with more decimals?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

uint public _totalSupply = 2100000000 * ( 10 ** 2 );
uint8 public constant decimals = 2;

uint public _totalSupply = 2100000000 * ( 10 ** 18 );
uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

First one with 2 decimals cost over 4000000 for estimated gas limit but one with 18 decimals show around 80000.
They have similar gas price (around 20-35)

Why does one cost more than other?